# Getting error while checking User Already Exists in MySQL database using Java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have tried some code to check that user is already exist in database or not while doing registration. But I am getting error like this. What am I getting wrong?

I am using Netbeans 8.2, Apache Tomcat, and MySQL database (XAMPP).

This is my registration.jsp page

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Registration JSP Page</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: lightblue;
      }
      
      #wgtmsrnew {
        width: 153px;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function validateForm() {
        alert("User Registered Successfully");
        return true;
      }
    </script>


  </head>

  <body>
    <form method="post" action="registrationJSPScript.jsp" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      <center>
        <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="5">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="2">Register</th>
              <p><b>Please fill in this form to create an account.</b></p>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Z ID</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="zid" value="" required="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>First Name</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="" required="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Last Name</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="lname" value="" required="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Mail ID</td>
              <td><input type="email" name="mailid" value="" required="" /></td>
            </tr>

              <td>Password</td>
              <td><input type="password" name="pass" required="" value="" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{8,12}$" required title="8 characters minimum,At least 1 Uppercase,At least 1 Lowercase,At least 1 number,At least 1 Symbol, symbol allowed --> !@#$%^&*_=+-"
                /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
              <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">Already registered!! <a href="loginJSP.jsp">Login Here</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </center>
    </form>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: You forgot to add the error (and to indicate where it's being raised)

Comment: pls post error log

Comment: What logically defines whether or not a user already exists in your table?

Comment: I have added error log. please check

Comment: While doing registration, when he/she clicks on submit button in registration page. Then alert should generate as User Already exist in database

Comment: After fixing the obvious SQL injection aspects of this (that is probably causing the current exception), and defining a uniqueness critiera (`zid`?). Make `zid` a primary key. If the insert fails with a duplicate key exception, catch this as your "already exists" criteria.

Comment: You have written `insert` query and you are using `executeQuery` instead of `executeUpdate` ?  Also how do you get `rs.getString("zid")` ? you never use `select` query ?  **Note**  : use [Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: I have made zid as a primary key and I don't want zid as auto increment. Now, when I do registration first time with zid as 1234 then successfully registered alert generated. And when I do registration second time with zid as 1234 then it gives me  error at line 31    " 31:     int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into dmsmembers(zid, first_name, last_name, mailid, department, division, location, pass, regdate) values ('" + zid + "','" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "','" + department + "','" + division + "','" + location + "','" + pwd + "', CURDATE())"); 
". above source code updated.

Comment: @priyadhanba you need to use `select` query first to check if that `zid` already exist in table . i.e : `select *from tablename where zid ='" + zid + "'` and if exist put an `alert` else write `insert` query.Also use `try-catch` to handle your exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check first if your `zid` enter by user is already present or not using `select` query and then if `user` exist just put an alert ,else `insert` record in db and your code will look like somewhat below:

```
   try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms","root", "");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM dmsmembers WHERE zid=?";//getting username
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            //setting value for ?
            ps.setString(1,zid);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            //checking if record with zid exist if yes do below  
            if(rs.next()){
            //put alert here
             out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
            out.println("alert('User Already Exists');");
            out.println("</script>");

            }else{
            //if zid doesn't exist insert new record
            int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into dmsmembers(zid, first_name, last_name, mailid, department, division, location, pass, regdate) values ('" + zid + "','" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "','" + department + "','" + division + "','" + location + "','" + pwd + "', CURDATE())");
            if (i > 0) {
                //response.sendRedirect("loginJSP.jsp");
                 //insert successfull alert message and redirect
                 out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                 out.println("alert('Registration Successfull!');");
                 out.println("location='loginJSP.jsp';");
                 out.println("</script>");
                } else {
                //not inserted have some error print here

                }

            }

            } catch(Exception e){
            //print error if any
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: your above code worked for me. Thank you so much yaar. but my question is when I click on Submit button in registration page then two alerts generated, one is "User Registered Successfully" and Second is "User already exist". I was trying to enter duplicate entry while registration and clicked on submit then also "User Registered Successfully" alert generated (I know I am entering duplicate zid) but not inserted into database, then after "User Already Exist" alert generated. Could you please check my registration.jsp page I have posted above .

Comment: don't use `javascript` in this you can put your `alert` code directly in your `registrationJSPScript.jsp` page i.e : in else part .

Comment: I have added "User Registered Successfully" alert here but not worked :( if (i > 0) {
                //session.setAttribute("userid", user);
                
                response.sendRedirect("loginJSP.jsp");
               // out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<a href='index.jsp'>Go to Login</a>");
            } else {
                //response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
                out.println("alert('User Registered Successfully');");
            }

Comment: check above code i have added `alert` in if part of i.e : `if (i > 0) {` . it should work .

Comment: i have written like this inside if(i > 0) :- %>
                <script>
                alert("User Registered Successfully!!!");
                window.location= "loginJSP.jsp";
                </script>
                <%

Comment: Hi swati, could you suggest an idea for this : I am doing file upload program(one or multiple files) and it is successful. and I have one link i.e. View All Files. I want only that files which are uploaded by respective user. but in my program, all files displayed. When user login then he/she can see only his/her files not other users files.How to do it?

Comment: i have already answer this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56060996/10606400)

Answer (score 0):

Use try-catch block.It will work .