# How to display Z ID on home.jsp page at right side to welcome user or welcome Z ID

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am trying to show respective user "Z ID" at upper right side corner on home.jsp page. I have done some modifications in my code using EL concept but for me it's not working. When user login then it redirects to home.jsp page and on home.jsp page I want to show user's Z ID. What I am getting wrong?

This is my Home.jsp page

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <style>
      h1 {
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px red;
      }
      
      .container {
        width: 90%;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 100px auto;
        background: #ddd;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 250px;
      }
      
      .box {
        width: 250px;
        height: 300px;
        background: #2495ff;
        margin: 0px 10px;
        transition: 1s;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      
      .box:hover {
        transform: scale(1.3);
        background: #2495ff;
        z-index: 2;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      
      body {
        background-color: lightblue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <br>
    <center>
      <h1>Welcome to Document Management System...</h1>
    </center>
    <br>

    <%
            
        String zid = request.getParameter("zid");
        if(zid != null){
            HttpSession sess = request.getSession();
            sess.setAttribute("zid",zid);
        }
            
        %>
      <div id="top">
        Hello ${zid.zid}
      </div>


      <div class="container">
        <div class="box"><b>New Document Upload</b></div>
        <div class="box"><b>View All Files</a></b></div>
        <div class="box"><b>Search or Extract Document</b></div>
        <div class="box"><b>Edit Profile</b></div>

      </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

This is my login.jsp page

```html
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Login Page</title>
      <style>
        body {
          background-attachment: fixed;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <form method="post" action="loginscriptJSP.jsp">
        <center>
          <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="3">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Login Here</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Z ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="zid" value="" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pass" value="" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Yet Not Registered!! <a href="registrationJSP.jsp">Register Here</a></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </form>

    </body>

    </html>
```

This is my loginscriptJSP.jsp page

```html
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>login script JSP Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>


      <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
        <%
    String zfid = request.getParameter("zid");    
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms",
            "root", "");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from dmsmembers where zid='" + zfid + "' and pass='" + pwd + "'");
    if (rs.next()) {
        session.setAttribute("zfid", zfid);
        //out.println("welcome " + userid);
        //out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
        response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
    } else {
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        out.println("alert('Invalid username or password');");
        out.println("location='loginJSP.jsp';");
        out.println("</script>");
        
        
    }
%>





    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: instead of `${zid.zid}` write `${zid}` it should work.

Comment: @Swati not working

Comment: then try with `${sessionScope.zid}` or  `${param.zid}`

Comment: not worked yaar  :-(

Comment: In `loginscriptJSP.jsp` you have setAttribute with name `zfid` .. use `${sessionScope.zfid}` or `${zfid}` to access the same in home.jsp page .

Comment: Thank you so much @Swati ${sessionScope.zfid} it worked. You helped me a lot. Thanks once again

Comment: @Swati yesterday I was trying to implement "User Already Exist in MySQL database". Could you please help me with this?  this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59960659/getting-error-while-checking-user-already-exists-in-mysql-database-using-java